# Can't upgrade from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, qt, xdg

Im trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, but the upgrade process stopped at the 'Installing the upgrades' step.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a bug with a display manager (ly, sddm, lightdm, or w/e) not setting the XDG environment variables before they boot up the window manager. I know for a fact that this problem exists in i3 / sway in some configurations with ly. But, without knowing what you're using there I can only guess. :)

You can work around the problem though by typing:

```
echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
# if not blank, this is not the problem!
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$(id -u)"
```

in the terminal, before you run the command. That of course, is providing you have something in that folder and provided you're not missing anything else.

Comment: Thank you, trying the upgrade from the terminal (which had the variable properly assigned) solved the issue.